# What could stop excessive plastic surgery in a society based on popularity?

Tags: society, trends

In other words, how can I stop everyone in the society from looking the same? And I'm talking about facial surgery, not weight loss.

To specify the title, the social system of this society is popularity.

For a bit of background, the society involves everyone being supplied with the basic supplies they need, but they also get a certain amount of credits each month to spend on luxuries. This includes surgery, so technically every person could get it done yearly or even monthly, but I don't want everyone to look the same.

Maybe the government can intervene? Or maybe it's just taboo? I honestly don't know why people wouldn't do that if they could.

Comment: When you say "rules" - do you mean rules imposed from above, ie government or legislation or do you mean what might evolve naturally. We'd need to know much more about your setup to answer the question.

Comment: Rich people do not look identical in our world either. Being exotic is beauty of its own.

Comment: Your question title hints at other defining features of this world, which aren't mentioned in the question. As the question is posed, it's really not that different from the real world - there are many people out there with disposable income that they spend on luxuries, but not everyone is spending it on plastic surgery. Some people would prefer other luxuries to plastic surgery, or wouldn't want plastic surgery even if it's free.

Comment: Why is excessive plastic surgery a problem that needs addressing? And even if they *do* all get facial surgery, why would they look "the same"? Do Michael Jackson, Cher, and Lil Kim look the same?  What about [these people](https://www.insider.com/extreme-plastic-surgery-2018-1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple basic tenets your society must espouse:

- A valuing of individualism and originality over conformity and standardization in fashion and appearance. Your society must fundamentally reject the old adage, "imitation is the highest form of flattery", and instead encourage individuals in the general case to self-innovate, taking risks and thinking outside the box. Even as only the "best" ideas get the most approval, copying those ideas must be seen as producing a "vanilla" result - bland, derivative, uninspired - and "vanilla" can't be the flavor of ice cream most people like.
- A true psychological preference for "natural" beauty of the human form (in all its permutations). Your face is your identity, it's what makes you you in society, and nobody else has it. The society therefore encourages in the general case for all individuals to avoid "disfigurement" in the form of cosmetic products or services beyond basic cleanliness, up to and including cosmetic surgery.

These tenets, however, are problematic when approaching sociology from an organic, evolutionary perspective. Simply put, these things are counter to how humans have been conditioned to think by their own society and the wider environment for tens of thousands of years (and probably millions of years of cerebroneural evolutionary development in nonhuman animals before that). First and foremost, humans are social creatures; we need to *belong*. That in turn usually requires us to demonstrate that we're "one of the guys" or "one of the girls", which from a very basic standpoint requires us to demonstrate that we conform to that group's acceptable norms. On top of that, there are societal preferences for appearance, especially for women but men also, generally based on what that society views as desirable in a sexual mate. These include youth, health, wealth, fertility and childbearing ability. These things generally increase the likelihood that the person you are considering will be able to live a nice long life with you, including making and raising a successive generation that is well-prepared and positioned to succeed in the world.

These basic traits are part of the very foundation of human society; not everyone considers the same traits to be acceptable, or to indicate the same (or any) measure of potential for success, but there are traits meeting all these criteria in any human society, and those who do not personify them have historically been cast out to the fringes of society if not entirely.

So, to make your society plausible, there has to be some overall, long-running societal benefit identified to this celebration of diversity and individuality. This may have come about through some social enlightenment, or (less likely) it has been evident to your society as long as they've known. Whatever this foundation is, if it's plausible, then your depiction of this society will be that much more believable. This is probably going to be something you can't hand-wave; there has to be a logically cogent explanation, otherwise this society, whether utopian (ideals of a near-future Earth in which diversity of humanity is truly celebrated) or dystopian (Hunger Games Capitol, basically a million people for whom "peacocking" is how they posture themselves in society), will fall flat.

Answer (score 7):

People value distinctness. Being popular almost always requires standing out in some way. Plastic surgery to match the ideal of "beauty" might be one route people take, but there's plenty more unique ones, especially if a large number of people start looking similar.

Look how the acceptance of piercings, tattoos, and dyed hair has opened up how some "popular" people look these days. If plastic surgery was as cheap as facial piercings or tattoos are, people might use their surgeries to make themselves look even more different.

You could also enter a legal barrier where rich and powerful celebrities "patent" their look so other popular people can't copy their face directly. Alternatively they could pay an exorbitant rate based on the popularity of the person in question's face.

So basically you can't copy Brad Pitt's face because it's legally protected, and if you find a way to get it done anyways, good luck getting popular without getting in trouble for "facial copy-right violations".

Answer (score 4):

**Risk of scarring/death.**

No matter how careful your surgeons are, there is always a risk that something will go wrong. This usually takes the form of small-yet-ungainly scars; however, mistakes with anesthesia can cause brain damage or even death.

**This is a real-world problem.** A friend of mine who is an R.N. (registered nurse) once told me that she is never going to have plastic surgery, as "too many people don't wake up."

Answer (score 3):

**Even if money is not capped, the access to the profession of plastic surgeon is!**

Even if you have some money that can be spent on plastic surgery, good luck to find one!

If the profession of plastic surgeon requires to get a degree from a very difficult closed-number university course, the number of specialists who can perform a plastic surgery will still remain relatively low, and consequently, even the number of actual surgeries will stay low.

So, in order to undergo a plastic surgery, you need to enter a veeeeery long waiting list or invest in a "premium" ticket that allows to jump the queue, but that only few people can afford**...
So only some tens thousands people every year can do it!

**  this could be the rationale why plastic surgeons would push for limiting the access to university courses and - consequently - the number of new colleagues

Comment: what if it's done by computers?

Comment: @Alexandra Eagle  Well, I've supposed that the technologic level of this scenario wouldn't be too different from our world... And anyway, I wouldn't trust a computer's esthetic sense, since they like to put functionality over beauty... I would fear to wake up from anesthesia with a pair of telescopic ears or a prehensile trunk in place of the nose! :)

Comment: @McTroopers A computer values what you tell it to value. If it's programmed with a definition of "aesthetics", it can maximize that just as easily (maybe *more* easily) than it can with a definition of "utility".

Answer (score 1):

Copyrights. Recently passed legislation (not really, but imagine it for the purposes of this post) permits celebrities to copyright their appearances. The healthcare workers involved in the surgery are jointly liable for infringing works. Not only do you - the patient - get socked for hundreds of thousands of dollars in statutory fees, but the doctors, nurses, anesthesiologists and other get beaten up by lawyers.

[Note](https://cakeboss.com/selling-cakes-with-copyrighted-characters/): this [sort](https://boingboing.net/2017/01/23/the-bizarre-story-of-trumps.html) of [legal battle](https://www.wickedgoodies.net/2017/02/cake-trademark-copyright-law/) happens with [cakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cake_copyright).

Answer (score 1):

It's considered 'cheating' or is taboo in some way, so people who have it done need to hide it, which obviously limits them to more subtle alterations. Because of this, it usually isn't worth the cost and the effort so most people don't do it.

To some extent we have a taboo like this in our own society.

Answer (score 0):

Easy: the antibiotics, due to excessive, wrong use are no longer working. Surgery is a russian roulette, with a lot of people succumbing to post operatory infections and some hospitals are death traps. So people will learn to avoid plastic surgeries.

Answer (score 0):

A few things could do it:

1. **A complete aversion to fake.**  Even the accusation of being fake might be enough to have a famous person trot out their medical
   records or have MRIs done to prove that they aren't fake.  This
   could affect other aspects of society as well.
2. **The body is a Temple.**  Some religions consider it blasphemous to alter the body (tattoos, piercings, and cosmetic surgery).  If this
   was a tenant of the mainstream religion (even if that religion is no
   longer strictly adhered to) it would cause issues for anyone found
   to have had cosmetic surgery.

If both of those occur together, I can see cosmetic surgery as even being considered.  In fact, some people with mutilations may prefer to not even use corrective surgery as however they look now would be better than looking fake.

Another thing that could do it in conjunction with either or both of the above:

**Veneration of the elderly.**  In many cultures, the older you are, the higher status you have.  If this was worldwide, anything that makes you look younger would be counter productive.

On its own, this wouldn't prevent surgery to make the current you look better except that plastic surgery does not age well.  In 10-20 years, those collagened lips start looking lumpy.  The bone can pull away from plastic implants.  Stretched skin may become thin and look over stretched.  It may not do your status any good to have such obvious (and now counter productive) work done.